# Jupyterlab Desktop v3.6.1-1 with Python 3.10.5 and Above

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I have installed Jupyterlab Desktop v3.6.1-1 and Python 3.11.2. I am unable use installed Python 3.11.2 as the customized python for the Jupyterlab Desktop application. Appreciate help in correcting this.

The re-installed Jupyterlab application has initialized but now unable to change the default Python to version 3.11.2. Currently working with the bundled python version.

@krassowski Please see below as part the logs (i am unable to paste the entire log file here):

> [2023-02-11 16:38:41.440] [error] Failed to create free server Error:
> No default environment found!
> at C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\build\out\main\registry.js:191:32
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) [2023-02-11 16:38:41.446]
> [error] (node:6444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No
> default environment found!
> at C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\build\out\main\registry.js:191:32
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) (Use `JupyterLab --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) [2023-02-11 16:38:41.447] [error] (node:6444)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) [2023-02-11 16:45:13.067] [error] Failed to fetch
> news list: FetchError: request to https://blog.jupyter.org/feed
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND blog.jupyter.org
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 16:45:17.689]
> [error] Failed to check for updates: FetchError: request to
> https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/latest.yml
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 16:46:19.904]
> [warn]  Language pack 'English_Nigeria' not valid! [2023-02-11
> 16:46:27.187] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 16:46:30.497] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 16:53:02.212] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 16:53:35.630] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 16:53:50.726] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 16:55:54.949] [error] Failed to fetch news list: FetchError: request
> to https://blog.jupyter.org/feed failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> blog.jupyter.org
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 16:55:59.569]
> [error] Failed to check for updates: FetchError: request to
> https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/latest.yml
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 16:56:54.954]
> [warn]  Language pack 'English_Nigeria' not valid! [2023-02-11
> 16:57:00.018] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 16:57:09.824] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 16:57:19.164] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting in 0 seconds.
> [2023-02-11 16:57:22.449] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through
> the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching
> individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early
> [2023-02-11 16:57:47.999] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through
> the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching
> individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early
> [2023-02-11 16:58:09.553] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting in 0
> seconds. [2023-02-11 16:58:12.652] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets
> through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to
> fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too
> early [2023-02-11 16:58:17.116] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting
> in 0 seconds. [2023-02-11 16:58:20.276] [warn]  Failed to fetch
> ipywidgets through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback
> to fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed
> too early [2023-02-11 17:01:38.119] [error] Failed to fetch news list:
> FetchError: request to https://blog.jupyter.org/feed failed, reason:
> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND blog.jupyter.org
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 17:01:42.745]
> [error] Failed to check for updates: FetchError: request to
> https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/latest.yml
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 17:01:56.022]
> [warn]  Language pack 'English_Nigeria' not valid! [2023-02-11
> 17:02:01.733] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 17:04:06.215] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting in 0 seconds.
> [2023-02-11 17:04:09.302] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through
> the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching
> individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early
> [2023-02-11 17:04:39.659] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting in 0
> seconds. [2023-02-11 17:04:42.809] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets
> through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to
> fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too
> early [2023-02-11 17:04:49.065] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting
> in 0 seconds. [2023-02-11 17:04:52.815] [warn]  Failed to fetch
> ipywidgets through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback
> to fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed
> too early [2023-02-11 19:20:22.080] [error] Failed to check for
> updates: FetchError: request to
> https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/latest.yml
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 19:39:42.236]
> [error] Failed to fetch news list: FetchError: request to
> https://blog.jupyter.org/feed failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
> blog.jupyter.org
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 19:39:42.632]
> [error] Failed to check for updates: FetchError: request to
> https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/latest.yml
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-11 19:40:25.249]
> [warn]  Language pack 'English_Nigeria' not valid! [2023-02-11
> 19:40:37.525] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-11
> 19:44:41.015] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting in 0 seconds.
> [2023-02-11 19:44:44.158] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through
> the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching
> individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early
> [2023-02-11 19:45:50.216] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting in 0
> seconds. [2023-02-11 19:45:53.375] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets
> through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to
> fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too
> early [2023-02-11 19:53:05.789] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting
> in 0 seconds. [2023-02-11 19:53:08.999] [warn]  Failed to fetch
> ipywidgets through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback
> to fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed
> too early [2023-02-11 19:55:14.794] [warn]  Connection lost,
> reconnecting in 0 seconds. [2023-02-11 19:55:17.916] [warn]  Failed to
> fetch ipywidgets through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel,
> fallback to fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was
> closed too early [2023-02-11 19:57:07.721] [error] Uncaught TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')
> [2023-02-11 20:02:05.760] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting in 0
> seconds. [2023-02-11 20:02:08.896] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets
> through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to
> fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too
> early [2023-02-11 20:02:21.380] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting
> in 0 seconds. [2023-02-11 20:02:24.524] [warn]  Failed to fetch
> ipywidgets through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback
> to fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed
> too early [2023-02-12 00:21:48.371] [error] Failed to fetch news list:
> FetchError: request to https://blog.jupyter.org/feed failed, reason:
> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND blog.jupyter.org
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-12 00:21:48.816]
> [error] Failed to check for updates: FetchError: request to
> https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/releases/latest/download/latest.yml
> failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com
> at ClientRequest. (C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1505:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:481:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) [2023-02-12 00:22:14.991]
> [error] Failed to start server Error: Failed to launch Jupyter Server
> at C:\JupyterLab\resources\app.asar\build\out\main\server.js:254:28
> [2023-02-12 00:23:05.678] [warn]  Language pack 'English_Nigeria' not
> valid! [2023-02-12 00:23:16.025] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets
> through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to
> fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too
> early [2023-02-12 00:23:49.738] [warn]  Connection lost, reconnecting
> in 0 seconds. [2023-02-12 00:23:53.079] [warn]  Failed to fetch
> ipywidgets through the "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback
> to fetching individual model state. Reason: Control comm was closed
> too early [2023-02-12 00:55:02.375] [warn]  Connection lost,
> reconnecting in 0 seconds. [2023-02-12 00:55:02.376] [warn]
> Connection lost, reconnecting in 0 seconds. [2023-02-12 00:55:09.472]
> [warn]  Language pack 'English_Nigeria' not valid! [2023-02-12
> 00:55:13.327] [warn]  Failed to fetch ipywidgets through the
> "jupyter.widget.control" comm channel, fallback to fetching individual
> model state. Reason: Control comm was closed too early [2023-02-12
> 00:55:18.537] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
> [2023-02-12 00:55:18.545] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch
> [2023-02-12 00:57:19.544] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to
> fetch [2023-02-12 00:57:19.545] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to
> fetch [2023-02-12 00:59:19.776] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError:
> Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 00:59:19.778] [error] Error in Auto-Save
> Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:01:20.546] [warn]  Showing error:
> TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:01:20.547] [error] Error in
> Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:03:42.759] [warn]  Showing
> error: TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:03:42.761] [error]
> Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:05:44.533] [warn]
> Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:05:44.534]
> [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:08:44.536]
> [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12
> 01:08:44.537] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12
> 01:10:44.515] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
> [2023-02-12 01:10:44.516] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch
> [2023-02-12 01:13:44.505] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to
> fetch [2023-02-12 01:13:44.505] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to
> fetch [2023-02-12 01:15:44.518] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError:
> Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:15:44.519] [error] Error in Auto-Save
> Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:17:44.513] [warn]  Showing error:
> TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:17:44.514] [error] Error in
> Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:19:44.524] [warn]  Showing
> error: TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:19:44.525] [error]
> Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:22:44.544] [warn]
> Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:22:44.546]
> [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:24:43.765]
> [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12
> 01:24:43.768] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12
> 01:27:42.509] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
> [2023-02-12 01:27:42.512] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch
> [2023-02-12 01:30:44.520] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError: Failed to
> fetch [2023-02-12 01:30:44.521] [error] Error in Auto-Save Failed to
> fetch [2023-02-12 01:32:44.564] [warn]  Showing error: TypeError:
> Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:32:44.565] [error] Error in Auto-Save
> Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:35:43.770] [warn]  Showing error:
> TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:35:43.772] [error] Error in
> Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:37:42.788] [warn]  Showing
> error: TypeError: Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:37:42.790] [error]
> Error in Auto-Save Failed to fetch [2023-02-12 01:39:44.545] [warn]
> Showing error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Please provide more details: a) do you have the latest jupyterlab installed in the custom environment? b) what  is the content of logs: Start application from command line as `jlab --verbose 4`, wait until it settles, Copy-paste the logs from the following location: on Linux: `~/.config/jupyterlab-desktop/logs/main.log`, on macOS: `~/Library/Logs/jupyterlab-desktop/main.log` on Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\jupyterlab-desktop\logs\main.log` (and optionally `renderer.log` but it is likely irrelevant).

Comment: @krassowski Please see below as the logs and also note i did not select the python version embedded in the current Jupyterlab Desktop as the default python version. I had to repeat the installation/uninstall before the current installed version in use.